# Efficiently using a 'for loop' over a range of dates: bash script

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, imagemagick, raspberry-pi

I have a bash script that I am using for a photography project that I have been working on.  In short, I have a Raspberry Pi camera taking pictures of a sunrise everyday.  It takes those pictures and compresses them into a movie and uploads it to my Dropbox account.  Then I have another Raspberry Pi at home that downloads the movies, and turns them back into still pictures.  I am using the program Image Magick to make a montage of those pictures so they layout in a nice grid.  It should be pretty beautiful when its done.

The problem is that my bash script is pretty inefficient, and it requires a lot of work to prepare it.  My limited programming knowledge is an obstacle here.  My script is posted below.

The photos are in folders labeled by date (YYYYMMDD) and the photos themselves are labeled by date and sequenced (YYYYMMDD-0001.jpg, YYYYMMDD-0002.jpg, etc).  There are 1440 pictures in each folder.

I have a for loop that goes through each folder that I identify as a variable.  I would prefer to have a for loop that finds every folder in a range of dates (20151001 - 20161001).  Is there a more efficient way to write this?  I have poked around for something, but I haven't had a lot of luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
DA="20151001/20151001-";  
DB="20151002/20151002-";  
DC="20151003/20151003-";  
DD="20151004/20151004-";  
DE="20151005/20151005-";  
DF="20151006/20151006-";  
DG="20151007/20151007-";  
DH="20151008/20151008-";  
DI="20151009/20151009-";  
DJ="20151010/20151010-";  
DK="20151011/20151011-";  
DL="20151012/20151012-";  
DM="20151013/20151013-";  
DN="20151014/20151014-";  
DO="20151015/20151015-";  
DP="20151016/20151016-";  
DQ="20151017/20151017-";  
DR="20151018/20151018-";  
DS="20151019/20151019-";  
DT="20151020/20151020-";  


counter=10000  
for f in ${DA}*.jpg; do  
let "counter+=1"  

#Image Magick Montage lays the pictures out in a 10X2 grid.  
montage -tile 10x2 -geometry +1+1 ${DA}${counter:1}.jpg ${DB}${counter:1}.jpg ${DC}${counter:1}.jpg ${DD}${counter:1}.jpg ${DE}${counter:1}.jpg ${DF}${counter:1}.jpg ${DG}${counter:1}.jpg ${DH}${counter:1}.jpg ${DI}${counter:1}.jpg ${DJ}${counter:1}.jpg ${DK}${counter:1}.jpg ${DL}${counter:1}.jpg ${DM}${counter:1}.jpg ${DN}${counter:1}.jpg ${DO}${counter:1}.jpg ${DP}${counter:1}.jpg ${DQ}${counter:1}.jpg ${DR}${counter:1}.jpg ${DS}${counter:1}.jpg ${DT}${counter:1}.jpg /media/KINGSTON/montage${counter:1}.jpg  
done
```

Answer (score 1):

So you're asking the fastest way to only loop through `20151001` through `20161001`? I'd do it like this:

```
counter=10000  
for d in 20*; do
    if [ 20151001 -le $d ] && [ $d -le 20161001 ]; then
        for f in $d/$d-*.jpg; do
            let "counter+=1"
            montage -tile 10x2 -geometry +1+1 ${DA}${counter:1}.jpg ${DB}${counter:1}.jpg ${DC}${counter:1}.jpg ${DD}${counter:1}.jpg ${DE}${counter:1}.jpg ${DF}${counter:1}.jpg ${DG}${counter:1}.jpg ${DH}${counter:1}.jpg ${DI}${counter:1}.jpg ${DJ}${counter:1}.jpg ${DK}${counter:1}.jpg ${DL}${counter:1}.jpg ${DM}${counter:1}.jpg ${DN}${counter:1}.jpg ${DO}${counter:1}.jpg ${DP}${counter:1}.jpg ${DQ}${counter:1}.jpg ${DR}${counter:1}.jpg ${DS}${counter:1}.jpg ${DT}${counter:1}.jpg /media/KINGSTON/montage${counter:1}.jpg  
        done
    fi
done
```

I only go into the directories that satisfy 20151001 <= $d <= 20161001.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is probably using awk's range patterns :

```
for f in $(ls | awk '/20151001/,/20161001/')
do
    # sorry, I'll leave the montage command to you !
    ls $f/$f*.jpg
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option may be to use the `date` command to generate dates any number of days from your start day, so for example to get the date one day later than your start date:

```
date -d '2015/10/01 +1 day'
Fri Oct 2 00:00:00 BST 2015
```

Now you can use `+%Y%m%d` to format that how you want it, so it becomes:

```
date -d '2015/10/01 +1 day' +'%Y%m%d'
20151002
```

So, if you want the full year, one day at a time starting from 2015/10/01, you can do

```
for i in {0..365}; do
   date -d "2015/10/01 +$i days" +'%Y%m%d'
done
```

If you want that in a variable, you can do that like this:

```
for i in {0..365}; do
   folder=$(date -d "2015/10/01 +$i days" +'%Y%m%d')
   echo $folder
done
```